# Unable to add nodes to MAAS Server running in VirtualBox

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, maas

I have followed the tutorials [here](http://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/install.html) and [here](http://marcoceppi.com/2012/05/juju-maas-virtualbox/) . My MAAS master server (running Ubuntu 12.04 server) is already set up in a VirtualBox VM. I have not installed DHCP on this server as I already have a DHCP server on my LAN router. I am also able to access the MAAS web-interface from my host Ubuntu 12.04 desktop machine's web browser. However, when I try to add nodes to the MAAS server by using the "Multiple Server Install with MAAS" method of the Ubuntu 12.04 server ISO, the node does not get added to the MAAS server. For clarification, the node is also a VirtualBox VM.

After the network auto-configuration step has completed, I am presented with the following options:

- ubuntu-maas-master MAAS Server - (192.168.1.105:80)
- Specify MAAS by name or address
- Create a new MAAS on this server

So, I select the first option (ubuntu-maas-master MAAS Server), which is the correct IP address of my MAAS master server VM.

After this, the node VM sigkills all processes and shuts down. On the MAAS master server, I can see this error message in /var/log/maas/maas.log: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5809908/ .

Can anyone help me solve the problem so that I can test MAAS in VirtualBox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This method of installing is badly supported at the moment.  You need to PXE boot the node instead.

If you are using an external DHCP server, did you configure its "next server" setting to point at the MAAS server?  If that's not done, nothing will boot over the network using MAAS.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the problem. My DHCP server is located on my router and my router does not have a "next server" configuration parameter. I guess I will try to find some other solution.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that MAAS upstream has changed, and the client tools that performs the enlistment process has not been updated accordingly. Could you please file a bug for [1](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/maas-enlist), detailing this information please?

Comment: I have added a bug report here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/maas-enlist/+bug/1198639 . Let me know if you need any help. Thanks!