# MAAS nodes stuck on "maas-enlisting-node"

Tags: maas

I am trying to set up an MAAS cluster, but am having some issues adding nodes.
The nodes boot up from the TFTP server on the master server, display a login screen (with the hostname "maas-enlisting-node") and stop.

I cannot log in with ubuntu/ubuntu or with my SSH keys. The MAAS server is running DHCP and DNS on the network, and the TFTP boot appears to be loading everything without issues (I can screencap if you want)

Any ideas what's going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you get any error messages? If so, please add them to the question. What Ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to add nodes to MAAS Server running in VirtualBox](http://askubuntu.com/questions/314166/unable-to-add-nodes-to-maas-server-running-in-virtualbox)

Comment: No error messages in the console of the node, where would I check on the master server? I've tried using 12.4 and 13.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing is expected behavior. Once a machine enters into the maas-enlisting-mode, cloud-init will run certain code and will enlist the machine in MAAS. These may take a few minutes provided on how fast it can retrieve the packages from the Internet and install them. Once this finishes, the machines will power off by themselves and they will be available in the MAAS WebUI.

Comment: @guntbert turns out there was an internal networking issue with my setup. Andres' answer was correct after I resolved the issue.