# Unable to access MAAS nodes

Tags: maas

I am trying to access to MAAS nodes. I cannot access them with ubuntu user nor ssh from MAAS server. 
I've added SSH key in MAAS web interface. I need to install Virsh onto them, but I cannot even access them anyway.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Unfortunatly I cannot access to node from server via SSH, still asks for      madis@OS-baseVM:~$ ssh 192.168.0.21 The authenticity of host '192.168.0.21 (192.168.0.21)' can't be established. ECDSA key fingerprint is 91:a5:43:32:2b:d7:ec:56:f8:a5:7f:cb:97:dc:1b:f0. Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes Warning: Permanently added '192.168.0.21' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts. madis@192.168.0.21's password:

Answer (score 1):

```
ssh ubuntu@192.168.0.21
```

This will not work with a MAAS node from my experience.  You need to use the FQDN hostname you used to name the MAAS node.  If you are having DNS issues it will make this difficult.

```
ping OS-baseVM
```

I am assuming OS-baseVM is the name of the MAAS node you are trying to connect to.  If you start getting replies great hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd>.  If it errors out you have a DNS issue.

Simple fix to the DNS issue is to add the MAAS node names to your `/etc/hosts file`.

```
192.168.0.21  OS-baseVM
```

This is how I was able to log onto my first nodes.  This allows your MAAS server to see your nodes.  You then have to duplicate this on each node to see the MAAS server.  It is better to fix bind9, but currently I don't know how to do that.

In short, you are on the right track.  Make sure your SSH key is correct.  Make sure DNS is working.  Then `ssh ubuntu@OS-baseVM` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Get an look [here](https://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/troubleshooting.html) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/314166/unable-to-add-nodes-to-maas-server-running-in-virtualbox), I hope it helps you.

Comment: Unfortunatly I cannot access to node from server via SSH, still asks for password

Comment: madis@OS-baseVM:~$ ssh 192.168.0.21
The authenticity of host '192.168.0.21 (192.168.0.21)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is 91:a5:43:32:2b:d7:ec:56:f8:a5:7f:cb:97:dc:1b:f0.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '192.168.0.21' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
madis@192.168.0.21's password:

Comment: The ssh key is added to the 'ubuntu' user on the nodes that you boot. Try an SSH along the lines of "ssh ubuntu@192.168.0.21"